# Uniform Cauchyness

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Assume the sum of $|f_n|$ is uniformly cauchy. Does this imply that the sum of $(f_n)$ is uniformly cauchy?

My reasoning is yes, since every $f_n$ is bounded by $|f_n|$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes since
$$
\lVert
\sum_{n=k+1}^m f_n
\rVert\leq
\sum_{n=k+1}^m \lVert
f_n
\rVert=\sum_{n=k+1}^m \lVert
|f_n|
\rVert\to 0
$$
as $m\to \infty$ and $k\to \infty$ where $\lVert\cdot \rVert$ is the uniform norm.